# tableau to show both last and previous 12 month

Tags: date, tableau-api

In one worksheet, to display the measure value (Sales) of Last 12 Months(LTM) and Previous 12 Months(PTM) from the selected month.

Current Month is 2018-June , By default selection

PTM date range for the sales period as (2016-June to 2017-May)
LTM date range for the sales period as (2017-June to 2018-May)

If user selects different month from the drop down, let's select (Apr 2018)

PTM date range as (2016-Apr to 2017-Mar)
LTM date range as (2017-Apr to 2018-Mar)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a parameter. Here are the steps involved:

1. Create a date parameter

[image]

2. Create a calculated field as below(You might need to fine tune it to match your exact requirements)

[image]

3. Add the calculated field to filter card to show only 'SHOW'

[image]